# How to model a Letter Transportation business context in a database diagram?

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I am trying to crate entity-relationship diagram for a *transport company* database. This database should store information about *letters*, *deliveries*, moving *letters* from one *warehouse* to another, and historical information. It should allow tracking *letters*, e.g., checking what *letters* were on certain *date* in a specific *warehouse*.

The **process** I want to model looks like this:

- *letter* is collected from sender and it goes to *warehouse*,
- then it could be transferred between *warehouses*,
- at last, *letter* is *delivered* to *recipient*.

### Business rules

- *Letters* are sent and received by *People*, one *letter* can be sent by one particular *Person*, and also received by a specific *Person*.
- There can be many *People* in database, if a *Person* is stored in the database it must be *Sender* or *Receiver* of some *Letter*.
- *Transports* are made between different *Warehouses* and must consist of many *Letters*, *Letters* can be a part of multiple *Transports* (on different *Dates*)
- *Warehouses* store multiple *Letters*
- A *Letter* can be stored in few different *Warehouses* on different *Dates* (on ‘01.11’ it is in ‘Warehouse A’, and on ‘02.11’ in ‘Warehouse B’)
- *DateStorage* - contains information about when a *Letter* has arrived to certain *Warehouse*
- *Transports* are being done on certain *Date*, they depart from one *Warehouse* and go to another.
- *Letters* can be delivered to recipients. If *Delivery Attempt* fails - there could be more attempts.

### Current diagram

This is the database diagram I have created so far:

[image: ![Diagram]

Relationship between *Letters* and *Warehouses* means that when letter is picked up by courier it is put to that warehouse.

### Questions and current considerations

Is this diagram correct, what could I improve?

Is it OK that there are to relationship between transports and warehouses (from could be deduced from previous transports and initial warehouse of letter)?

Comment: Discussion on this question has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47885/discussion-on-question-by-igor-how-to-model-a-letter-transportation-business-con)** as requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you [stated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33369296#33369296) that the structure depicted in your diagram is part of a university project, the objective should be to make it as realistic as possible, so I consider that carrying out an interview (or a series of interviews) with the experts of a *correspondence company* might be very helpful (perhaps indispensable).

In this way, since creating a full and accurate entity-relationship diagram (or any of its derivatives) for this kind of business domain would require a much more in-depth examination (and, thus, a very long series of to-ings and fro-ings), the goal of this answer is to point you in the right direction with respect to the technical methods you might have to employ, presenting an expository analysis that includes my first draft of an IDEF1X model made up of elements that *seem* feasible, so that you can use it as a reference to capture the meaning of a *real* scenario.

## Central aspects

The way I see it, the aspects of the business domain analysis that require special attention are the *Events* in which a *Letter* might be involved; therefore, I will detail bellow a *hypothetical* context that consists of some supossed *Types of Event* that appear of relevance (but, naturally, you should confirm, modify or discard all the discussed points on your own).

## Considerations

I have listed the elements (brought up in [the talk we had via chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47885/discussion-on-question-by-igor-how-to-model-a-letter-transportation-business-con)) that I consider particularly helpful to work on forwarding the situation:

> - [A]t any time, I would like to know where the letter is - no matter if it is in some warehouse or it is being transported.
> - In my design sender is only the original sender of a letter (client of the company) and receiver (recipient) is a person to which letters is addressed - there is always one sender and one recipient for a letter.
> - [F]or one transport there can only be one courier.
> - One letter can be stored in up to about 10 warehouse. However number of all warehouses is much higher - few hundreds (or maybe even thousands).
> - My idea was to store every client (sender / recipient) in database. So if some person have send or received at least one letter it […] is in database (but if person sends / receives more letters it is in database only once).

## Business rules

Then, based on (a) such elements, (b) the content of your question, and (c) some estimations and assumptions that *appear* viable, I wrote the following formulations that describe the tentative interrelationships between the hypothetical *entity types* of significance (i.e., a substantial part of the *business context rules*, which serve the purpose of defining the corresponding *conceptual* model):

**Person, Letter and Address**

- A *Letter* is sent by exactly one *Person* (who plays the role of *Sender*)
- A *Person* sends zero-one-or-many *Letters*
- A *Letter* addresses exactly one *Person* (who carries out the role of *Addressee*)
- A *Person* (performing the role of *Addressee*) is addressed in zero-one-or-many *Letters*
- A *Person* keeps zero-one-or-many *Addresses*
- An *Address* is kept by zero-one-or-many *Persons*
- An *Address* locates the *Sender* of zero-one-or-many *Letters*
- An *Address* locates the *Addressee* of zero-one-or-many *Letters*

**Letter and Event**

- A *Letter* is involved in one-to-many *Events*
- An *Event* is classified by exactly one *EventType*
- An *Event* is

  - either a *Dispatch*<sup>1</sup>
  - or an *Exit*<sup>2</sup>
  - or a *Transport*<sup>3</sup>
  - or a *HalfwayStorage*<sup>4</sup>
  - or a *DeliveryAttempt*<sup>5</sup>
  - or a *Receiving*<sup>6</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Dispatch*. The *Event* that occurs when a certain *Person* leaves a specific *Letter* in a precise *Warehouse* so that it can take part in a transportation process.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *Exit*. The *Event* that happens when a particular *Letter* departs from a given *Warehouse* to start the transportation.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *Transport*. The *Event* that occurs when a certain *Letter* is being moved between distinct *Warehouses* while the transportation is taking place.</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *Halfway Storage*. The *Event* that happens when a concrete *Letter* is kept in an exact *Warehouse* in the middle of the transportation.</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup> *Delivery Attempt*. The *Event* that occurs when a certain *Person* (playing the role of *Courier*) tries to deliver a specific *Letter* to the *Person* who was addressed in it.</sub>

<sub><sup>6</sup> *Receiving*. The *Event* that happens when a certain *Letter* is received in the *Address* that locates the *Person* who was addressed in such *Letter*.</sub>

<sub>*Note:* Some of these *Types of Event* (or *Event Types*) might come about several times with respect to a certain *Letter* (e.g., a *Letter* could be involved in multiple *Transport* occurrences during a whole transportation process); other *Types of Event* appear to be constrained to a unique occurrence regarding a concrete transportation process (e.g., *Dispatch* and *Receiving*). On the other hand, a real business domain may entail more *Event Types*, and the ones discussed in this answer might simply not apply or could have distinct characteristics, that is why performing an analysis yourself is paramount. Furthermore, the terms I use here are merely explanatory, as they possibly are not equal to those employed in a real organization.</sub>

**Warehouse and the different subtypes of Event: Dispatch, Exit and HalfwayStorage**

- A *Warehouse* lodges zero-one-or-many *Dispatches*
- A *Warehouse* is the origin of zero-one-or-many *Exits*
- A *Warehouse* is the destination of zero-one-or-many *Exits*
- A *Warehouse* provides zero-one-or-many *HalfwayStorages*

**Vehicule and the distinct subtypes of Event: Exit, Transport and DeliveryAttempt**

- A *Vehicule* is utilized in zero-one-or-many *Exits*
- A *Vehicule* is employed in zero-one-or-many *Transports*
- A *Vehicule* is used in zero-one-or-many *DeliveryAttempts*

**Person and the subtypes of Event: Transport, DeliveryAttempt and Receiving**

- A *Person* (who plays the role of *Courier*) carries zero-one-or-many *Transports*
- A *Person* (who plays the role of *Courier*) conveys zero-one-or-many *DeliveryAttempts*
- A *Person* (who plays the role of *Courier*) participates in zero-one-or-many *Receivings*

## Illustrative IDEF1X model

Consequently, I built an IDEF1X<sup>a</sup> model in terms of all the points explained above. It is shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqRip.jpg) (make sure to click the link so that you can observe it at a higher resolution):

[image: Figure 1 - Letter Management IDEF1X Model - First Draft]

<sub><sup>a</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in december 1993 by the United States *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) some of the theoretical works authored by the originator of the [Relational Model](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [Entity-Relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

#### Event and its subtypes

As demonstrated in said model, there is a *supertype-subtype* relationship that comes about

- between `Event` (the *supertype*), and
- `Dispatch`, `Exit`, `Transport`, `HalfwayStorage`, `DeliveryAttempt` and `Receiving` (the *subtypes*).

The `Event` superentity type possesses the properties that are common to all its subtypes, i.e., `LetterNumber` and `DateTime` (exposed as a composite PRIMARY KEY [PK for brevity]), along with a *discriminator*, i.e., `EventTypeCode`, which indicates the exact kind of subtype instance that must be complementing each `Event` occurrence.

The PKs of `Dispatch`, `Exit`, `Transport`, `HalfwayStorage`, `DeliveryAttempt` and `Receiving` are, at the same time, FOREIGN KEYs (FKs) that point to the `Event` PK.

Every one of these subtypes displays the properties (or attributes) that apply exclusively to each of them, and some of those properties are FKs that illustrate the relationships that such subtypes have with some of the other entity types included in the model.

In this regard, you might find of help my answers to

- [“Modeling a scenario in which each Music Artist is either a Group or a Solo Performer”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644);
- [“How to model an entity type that can have different sets of attributes?”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149904/63644);
- [“Modelling a database structure for multiple user types and their contact information”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183119/63644);
- and the answers grouped by the [subtypes](/questions/tagged/subtypes) tag.

## Data samples

You did not clarify if the diagram is going to be used as a conceptual platform to construct a *logical database structure* (with proper tables, columns, column types and constraints) on a particular SQL database management system, but some data samples in tabular form will help to supply a more rounded answer that introduces further possibilities.

#### An EventType table

A table standing for the `EventType` entity type would fulfill a “look-up” role, and it may comprise the following rows:

```
 +-—————————————-+-————————————————-+-———————————————-+
 | EventTypeCode | Name             | Description     |
 +-—————————————-+-————————————————-+-———————————————-+
 | D             | Dispatch         | The event that… |
 +---------------+------------------+-----------------+
 | E             | Exit             | The event that… |
 +---------------+------------------+-----------------+
 | T             | Transport        | The event that… |
 +---------------+------------------+-----------------+
 | H             | Halfway Storage  | The event that… |
 +---------------+------------------+-----------------+
 | D             | Delivery Attempt | The event that… |
 +---------------+------------------+-----------------+
 | R             | Receiving        | The event that… |
 +---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Note that the `EventTypeCode` column, that has to be constrained as the PK, contains values that are *meaningful* (and, hence, are highly legible from the end user point of view), which enhances their usage when referenced from columns with FK constraints. At the same time, since the aforementioned values are physically *light* (as for their size in bytes), they behave quite fast regarding data retrieval processes and optimizes disk space consumption (mainly when pointed to from FKs).

#### An Event table

Then, let us suposse that a table dennoting the entity type named `Event` maintains the data points that follow for the *Letter* that is primarily identified by the *Number 1750*:

```
 +-————————————-+-———————————————————————-+-—————————————-+
 | LetterNumber | RegisteredDateTime      | EventTypeCode |
 +-————————————-+-———————————————————————-+-—————————————-+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-12 16:58:12.000 | D             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-15 09:12:05.000 | E             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-15 10:12:05.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-15 11:12:05.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-15 12:12:05.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-15 12:46:01.000 | H             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-17 06:24:07.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-17 07:24:07.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-17 08:24:07.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-17 09:10:13.000 | H             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-18 08:01:01.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-18 09:01:01.000 | T             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-18 09:27:12.000 | H             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-19 11:16:08.000 | D             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-19 11:48:03.000 | R             |
 +--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

As shown, that table would be retaining a sequence of all the *Events* in which *Letter Number 1750* was involved during a *transportation*. Of course, it would keep all the *Events* connected with all the pertinent *Letters*, but I only depicted a few hypothetical rows related to a supossed *Letter Number 1750* in order to simplify the example. The sort of “chronological” data structure held in this table is commonly referred to as a *time series*.

The `Event.EventTypeCode` column, which should be constrained as a FK, holds values that indicate the *kind* of *Event* that was registered (in a user-friendly manner, in accordance with the points mentioned in the previous section).

#### Application programs sharing data from tables representing the subtypes

A table with partial *Event* information (like the one previously deliberated) can be displayed in, e.g., a page of a web application program that provides a link that redirects to subsequent pages based on (a) the *Event Type*, (b) the *Letter Number* and (c) the *Date and Time* of the *Event* of interest.

In turn, the subsequent pages will exhibit the full *Event* information. E.g., if

- the `EventTypeCode` is *D*,
- the `LetterNumber` is *1750*, and
- the `DateTime` is *2016-11-12 16:58:12.000*,

then the redirection must take to a page that presents the complete `Dispatch` row, e.g.:

```
 +-————————————-+-———————————————————————-+-———————————————-+
 | LetterNumber | RegisteredDateTime      | WarehouseNumber |
 +-————————————-+-———————————————————————-+-———————————————-+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-12 16:58:12.000 |               x |
 +--------------+-------------------------+-----------------+
```

In case that

- the `EventTypeCode` is *T*,
- the `LetterNumber` is *1750*, and
- the `DateTime` is *2016-11-15 10:12:05.000*,

the redirection ought to take to a page that sets out the pieces of information of the whole `Transport` row:

```
 +-————————————-+-———————————————————————-+-——————————————-+-—————————-+-————————-+-—————————-+
 | LetterNumber | RegisteredDateTime      | VehiculeNumber | CourierId | Latitude | Longitude |
 +-————————————-+-———————————————————————-+-——————————————-+-—————————-+-————————-+-—————————-+
 | 1750         | 2016-11-12 16:58:12.000 |              w |         x |        y |         z |
 +--------------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

## Integrity, consistency and derivability

Evidently, a database structure with these characteristics entails a considerable set of constraints that must be put up to protect the integrity of the data, guaranteeing its consistency with the rules determined at the conceptual level (e.g., the cardinalities of the relationships between entity types/entity type instances).

Some of these constraints can be configured declaratively by way of PK and FK definitions, but others require resorting to a procedural approach —due to limitations in the declarative facilities provided by the major SQL database management systems—.

Among the rules that have to be enforced procedurally is the feature that (1) *each* `Event` row must be suplemented *at all times* by (2) the respective counterpart in *exactly one* of the tables representing the *subtypes*, which (3) must “comply with” the value enclosed in the `Event.EventTypeCode` column —standing for the *discriminator*—, so the utilization of [ACID TRANSACTIONS](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) is convenient to ensure that these circumstances are always met. Other possibility would be employing TRIGGERS, but they tend to make things messy.

And, yes, it would be practical to express and fix as VIEWs several queries that “combine” data from some or all the related tables in order to, e.g., simplify the pertinent data derivation.