# One-to-"Zero or One" Relation

Tags: mysql, database-design, subtypes

I have the following requirements:

- Every transaction has one of the following types; debit, credit, deposit, or withdraw.
- Debit or credit transactions must have a linked invoice record and no bank account record.
- Deposit or withdraw transactions must have a linked bank account record and no invoice record.

---

Currently my basic design is like this:

[image: Rough Database Design]

My current solutions are:

1. Have <del>a</del>two nullable foreign keys to the invoice and bank account tables in the transaction table. However, I believe a nullable foreign key column isn't a good design.
2. Have a foreign key in the invoice and bank account tables that link to the transaction table. However it's seems harder to query and it models a one-to-many relation (not one-to-optional-one relation I want).

Which approach that I outlined is a better solution? Or is there another way to meet my constraints that is even better?

Comment: See [“How to model an entity type that can have different sets of attributes”](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149904/63644) and the questions encompassed within the [`subtypes`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subtypes?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although very many NULLable columns are normally a sign of bad design, in some instances, it's perfectly legit to have them, and use the database `CONSTRAINTS` to make sure that the 0-1 relations and your business rules are kept. This would be your solution #1. Your solution #2 isn't easily helped by the database, you could eventually have one transaction without the corresponding rows in both `invoices` and `bank_accounts` tables.

Let's assume, for a moment, that you're *not* using MySQL<sup>1</sup> (at least, as of version 5.7).

Let's assume you are using another database that actually performs the checks<sup>2</sup>, it would make sense to use a schema like the following one, with one `invoice_id` and one `bank_account_id` columns, and the necessary constraints that guarantee that they're `REFERENCE`ing the proper rows in the proper tables (what you call *links*), and the `CHECKS` make sure that the proper ones appear, and the ones that do not correspond are not there:

```
CREATE TYPE transaction_type AS ENUM
    ('debit', 'credit', 'deposit', 'withdraw') ;
-- Note: this could be a table with four values (and probably four ids)    

CREATE TABLE invoices
(
    invoice_id integer /* serial */ PRIMARY KEY,
    other_data text
) ;

CREATE TABLE bank_accounts
(
    bank_account_id integer /* serial */ PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    other_data text
) ;

CREATE TABLE transactions
(
    transaction_id integer /* serial */ PRIMARY KEY, 
    type transaction_type,
    nominal decimal(10, 2),
    invoice_id integer REFERENCES invoices(invoice_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    bank_account_id integer REFERENCES bank_accounts(bank_account_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    -- Constraints for your business rules
    CONSTRAINT chk_debit_and_credit_must_have_bank_account 
         CHECK (case when type in ('debit','credit') then 
                    bank_account_id IS NOT NULL 
                else true end),
    CONSTRAINT chk_debit_and_credit_must_not_have_invoice 
         CHECK(case when type in ('debit','credit') then 
                   invoice_id IS  NULL 
                else true end),
    CONSTRAINT chk_deposit_and_withdraw_must_have_invoice 
        CHECK(case when type in ('deposit','withdraw') then 
                  invoice_id IS NOT NULL 
              else true end),
    CONSTRAINT chk_deposit_and_withdraw_must_not_have_bank_account 
        CHECK(case when type in ('deposit','withdraw') then 
                  bank_account_id IS NULL 
              else true end) 
) ;
```

With this in mind, and the following data...

```
-- Adding two invoices
INSERT INTO invoices
   (invoice_id, other_data)
VALUES
   (1, 'data for invoice 1'),
   (2, 'data for invoice 2')
;

-- Adding two bank accounts
INSERT INTO bank_accounts
   (bank_account_id, other_data)
VALUES
   (1000, 'Bank account 1000'),
   (1001, 'Bank account 1001')
;
```

... you can have one legit `INSERT`

```
-- Good credit and debit
INSERT INTO transactions 
    (transaction_id, type, nominal, invoice_id, bank_account_id)
VALUES
    (2000, 'credit', 1000.00, NULL, 1000),
    (2001, 'debit',   900.00, NULL, 1000) ;
```

... and some illegal ones (being rejected by the database)

```
-- Bad credit, it's got invoice
INSERT INTO transactions 
    (transaction_id, type, nominal, invoice_id, bank_account_id)
VALUES
    (2002, 'credit', 1000.00, 1, 1000) ;
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "transactions" violates check constraint "chk_debit_and_credit_must_not_have_invoice"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2002, credit, 1000.00, 1, 1000).
```

```
-- Bad credit, it's got not bank_account_id
INSERT INTO transactions 
    (transaction_id, type, nominal, invoice_id, bank_account_id)
VALUES
    (2003, 'credit', 1000.00, NULL, NULL) ;
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "transactions" violates check constraint "chk_debit_and_credit_must_have_bank_account"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2003, credit, 1000.00, null, null).
```

(and all other combinations)

A careful choice of names for the constraints can help a lot on debugging erroneous inserts or updates. If you need maximum speed, all the constraints can be reduced to just one single check expression. I normally would try to have the database *help me*, and keep it simple (4 easy names and 4 easy-to-read expressions, instead of a single one).

You can find all the setup at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=38780f7770549b665b8b2225551c1f70)*

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is the reason why:</sub>

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't help much, because from [MySQL's 5.7 manual on CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> **CHECK**
>
> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”.

<sup>2</sup><sub>I've used PostgreSQL. With some syntax variations, this would also work with SQL Server or Oracle</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest a third alternative: You can use **triggers** to check your business rules and fail the insert/update in a similar fashion a foreign key constraint would.

For your scenario I setup something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Transaction_BEFORE_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction_Table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

-- deposit, withdraw must have a bank account and no invoice
if NEW.`Type` in ('deposit','withdraw') then

   if not(select count(*) from Account_Table where id = NEW.id) 
      or (select count(*) from Invoice_Table where id = NEW.id) 
   then
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error message';
   end if;
-- credit, debit must have an invoice and no bank account
elseif NEW.`Type` in ('credit','debit') then
   if not(select count(*) from Invoice_Table where id = NEW.id) 
      or (select count(*) from Account_Table where id = NEW.id) 
   then
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Another error message';
   end if;
end if;
END
```

I've used SQLSTATE 45000 which is a generic state for user-defined exceptions. You may customize that and also set an appropiate error message.

You would also need to create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger that does a similar check.

There will be a performance penalty for abusing triggers this way. Each insert/update will run 2 selects on the other table. You should optimize the selects to be as fast as possible. On high transaction databases it could be a bad solution. So if you choose taking this route please test the impact before running it on production.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a transaction table, you have a [BankAccountTransaction] and a [CreditTransaction] table.

Yes, split you transaction in two tables, one has a FK to [BankAccount] and the another got a FK to [Invoice].

If the need arises you can create a "parent" [Transaction] table and use it to intermediate the relation between the above two tables to a table don't see the difference between them.
Or if that important only to report like queries you can create a view where you easily use a UNION.

```
                        +---------------------+                +---------------+
                        |                     |                |               |
        +---------------+  CreditTransaction  +---------------->    Invoice    |
+-------v------+        |                     |                |               |
|              |        +---------------------+                +---------------+
|              |
| Transaction  |
|              |
|              |          +------------------------+       +----------------+
+-------^------+          |                        |       |                |
        |                 | BankAccountTransaction |       | BankAccount    |
        +-----------------+                        +------->                |
                          |                        |       |                |
                          +------------------------+       +----------------+
```