# how to model an entity with two possibilities (sql)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have an payment entity that can take a form of bank transaction or cash. So, to achieve normalizing, I put cash payment primary key and transaction primary key in the payment entity. But, I doubt is the best approach, because payment can take just one form, and if the user made a mistake and want to change the payment method, I will have (myself as a developer) to make sure to delete the previous one (which is against normalizing ?!).

So i wonder if there is any better way to do this

[image]

Comment: This might be answered by https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153901/one-to-zero-or-one-relation?rq=1

Comment: `cash_payment` and `transaction` only differ in one FK. Why don't you just handle cash as a pseudo bank? Normalization is a nice habit, however, it should be done as much as it makes technical sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say the best approach, with the limited details provided. But, from what's provided, I think it's safe to say a transactions is a transaction, and a transaction is a transaction. It does not matter the form of the transaction.

As such, I assume transaction is going to be the "driving" table in your scenario. I.E. transactions will happen, and they'll either be by cash or bank account, and mapped accordingly. With that said, there can always be additional tables to provide additional detail, based on transaction type.

So, in your transaction table, add a column for `transaction_type` and remove `bank`. If a transaction is cash, you just flag it as cash in the `transaction_type` column, direclty in the `transaction` table. If cash, you'd likely need no additional details.

If the transaction was by bank_account, flag it as `bank_acct`. You could then have an intermediary table called `transaction_bank_map` that contains `transaction_id` and `bank_account_no` to link the transaction to the bank account the payment came from. This way, you're storing details of transactions once, and you're storing details of bank accounts only once.

This would remove the need for the `payment` and `cash_payment` tables.

**Or, skip the intermediary table**

Additionally, you could skip the intermediary table, and leave the `bank` column in the `transaction` table, and only populate the column when `tran_type = bank`. If most of your transaction will be  by bank account (which is likely the case for most businesses the days), this may be more appropriate.