# Best Practice - Database design for 'conditional join'

Tags: database-design, join, normalization, best-practices, subtypes

I need to create a database to store `Jobs`.
Each `Job` can have 1-* `Step`
Each `step` is classified as one of either `Type` A, B or C.
Each `Type` has specific details and other tables that join on them so putting them into the `Step` table is not an option.

This is depicted in the diagram below;

[image: Database model]

In this design there is a conditional join between `Step` and `TypeX` tables. I have read around and cannot find best practices for this kind of scenario, this feels very messy to me but i can't find a way around it. What would anyone else do?

Comment: You could add an intermediary table, with 4 columns. Column A being the the StepID, columnB being the TypeA ref, TypeB being typeb etc. If a join isn't needed, set the value to NULL. You'll then need to use COALESCE to retrieve values? It does seem messy though.

Comment: @George.Palacios thanks for the reply, I did think this but I couldn't help but think it was just pushing the problem onto another table, I will 100% need to do this join so doing this will not even save time on the load.

Comment: I would make the TypeX tables have the StepID as their primary key/clustered index and not bother with their own Identity.  Assuming it's a one to one relationship.    As an aside, to @George.Palacios comment, you could put the TypeA,B,C ref fields in the step table without the need for another table.

Comment: @JonathanFite I take you point about removing the `TypeXId` fields, it makes perfect sense. 
The problem I have with @George.Palacios comment is that I would have  a lot of NULL values throughout this table where 2/3 fields do not apply to the type represented in the row. Additionally, there are more tables that come off each `TypeX` table unique to each type.

Comment: @Intern87 Establishing some analogies, you may find [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149951/63644) (about a *supertype-subtype* structure) of help.

Comment: @MDCCL This is exactly (and then some) the type of information i'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: If you use the solution of adding multiple foreign keys, you should add a CHECK constraint that requires exactly (or at most) one of them to be populated.

Comment: @cliffordheath yes good point. Also I'd like to add I've since had a look around and this scenario is covered in 4th normal form.