# Internationalization of a Supertype-subtype

Tags: mysql, database-design, subtypes, localization

First of all, my apologies for tieing this question with another one, but that was the best way I could think to keep it simple and focused

[Months ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149904/105977) I was introduced to the supertype-subtype as solution for a problem that was more or less easy to present but I wasn't being able to solve

I understood the basic concept and was able to make it work with my modest knowledge and it worked quite well considering the original question is more than one year old.

However today I faced a problem I couldn't solve: Internationalization

Until now I had a table named `i18n` with a FOREIGN KEY pointing to the PRIMARY KEY of the supertype table (`Items`) just like all subtypes (`Car`, `Boat` and `Plane`) and when querying, among all columns of all subtypes, I include the column in this internationalization table with the translated strings joining everything by the supertype key.

Something like this:

`Items` structure:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| PK | Common Attribute #1 | Common Attribute #2 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

`Car` structure:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| PK | Reference | Attribute #1 | Attribute #2 |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

`Boat` structure:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| PK | Reference | Attribute #1 | Attribute #2 | Attribute #3 |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

`Plane` structure:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| PK | Reference | Attribute #1 | Attribute #2 | Attribute #3 | Attribute #4 |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

`i18n` structure:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| PK | Reference | Text |
+----+-----------+------+
```

> `Reference` is the FOREIGN KEY

I'm not exactly sure if this is the best approach, but it works because until now only one of the columns had text passive of internationalization — let's say `Attribute #1`. However, today, I noticed that one of the subtypes would need two columns to be translated and the way I was doing was considering only one — let's say `Attribute #4` of `Planes` Table.

I would like to do this right at database level instead of having some representative keyword to replace with the server-side language.

I tried to make a subquery for this second column to be translated but, not only it didn't work but that was smelling bad to me.

How could I do this?

[EDIT]

I thought for the best I should post my last attempt:

```
SELECT 
    `items`.`cid` AS `id`, `items`.`reference`, `items`.`GUID`,     # That's Users' Items Table

    `core`.`image`, `core`.`type`, `core`.`class` AS `classname`,   # That's the supertype

    `cars`.`attribute1`, `cars`.`attribute2`,

    `boats`.`attribute1`, `boats`.`attribute2`, `boats`.`attribute3`,

    `planes`.`attribute1`, `planes`.`attribute2`, `planes`.`attribute3`, `planes`.`attribute4`,

FROM `items`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core ON( ( items.reference = core.iid ) )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `catalog`.`cars` cars ON( items.reference = cars.reference )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `catalog`.`boats` boats ON( items.reference = boats.reference OR items.reference = boats.attribute3 )
                LEFT OUTER JOIN `catalog`.`planes` planes ON( items.reference = planes.reference )
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON( items.UserId = users.id )
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN i18n ON( items.reference = i18n.reference )

WHERE `i18n`.`langCode` = 'en'
        AND ( `items`.`GUID` = '4cca0b05-84b0-40af-8808-2379b32df35f' OR `items`.`GUID` = '41a0917e-8ccf-43a3-b52a-0ae0a09a2374' )

ORDER BY ( FIELD( `items`.`GUID`, '4cca0b05-84b0-40af-8808-2379b32df35f','41a0917e-8ccf-43a3-b52a-0ae0a09a2374' ) )
```

For this example, I used the subtype `Boats` to demonstrate the other column that could/should be translated.

I can retrieve all data I need of all subtypes at once with this query. It'll have several columns as `NULL` but when fetching data, with PHP (`PDO::FETCH_NAMED`, for what matters) everything works.

But I'm not being able to return the column with the text (`i18n.text`), only its Reference ID that matches the supertype Table (`Items.reference`).

I know, I know, I'm not including it as a column to be retrieved but, if I do, the first translatable column (`attribute1`) works, but then any other, that any subtype may have (here `boats.attribute3`) duplicates the value of `atribute1` instead of pulling its own referenced value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally hate having to join multiple tables to get the international variant of some text value so I make each attribute that needs to be internationalized either an XML column or a JSON column and then use the relevant functions to return the value that matches the language I need. This is an extremely extensible solution in the sense that you can add multiple languages very easily without adding new tables but does require you to modify your insert, update and selects to cope with it.

**XML Example:**

```
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <translations>
    <text key="en-US" value="pants"/>
    <text key="en-UK" value="trousers"/>
 </translations>'

SELECT ExtractValue([column], '/translations/text[@key="en-US"]');
```

**JSON Example:**

```
'{
    "en-US" : "pants",
    "en-UK" : "trousers"
 }'

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT([column], '$."en-US"');
```

I prefer to use JSON because it consumes less storage but I feel either approach is better than filling your database full of lookup tables. You just have to make sure that you use a character set for the XML or JSON that will support Unicode.

Comment: I've adjusted all subtypes tables I have to accommodate the JSON strings and it worked like a charm. However, two things are still holding me before go for it: 1) Is there a way to reuse the JSON path? Because I had to repeat it for every translatable column. 2) What about repeatable translatable content? Let's use the subtype `Cars` and assume an attribute named `type` (SUV, Truck, Sedan...). More than one record will fit the same category and this is a translatable attribute? Do I have to repeat the JSON structure on every single record? Or I can reuse it somehow?

Comment: You are completely correct - it is a trade off between having a small amount of duplication vs having translation tables. The only way to reduce duplication is to extract the JSON to its own table - in which case you really loose any benefit that was gained. I pass the locale as a parameter to the query which I then use to obtain the translation - this way the application controls which translation to return and you only have to write one query and not hard code the locale.

Comment: Well, to be perfectly fair you post didn't answer the question but it presented an alternative solution. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

**Charset?**

Are you saying that every `VARCHAR` is `latin1` today?  But tomorrow you need `utf8mb4`?

Plan A:

1. Disable foreign keys
2. ALTER TABLE ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
3. Enable FKs.

Plan B:

1. Dump the schemas; manually change charset
2. dump data without schemas
3. on a fresh machine load schemas, then data

Caution: "the devil's in the details."

**Phrases?**

If you are saying that you have a bunch of phrases in English today, but tomorrow you need each phrase in multiple languages, then there is a lot more to do than just modify the charset.

- Change phrases to have a language-independent id.
- Have a lookup table that maps these ids into each language (`phrase_id`, `language`, `phrase`)
- Suggest the standard 5-char (ASCII) lanbuages, such as `EN-US`, `EN-UK`, etc.  Don't bother to make separate ids for these, use them as is.
- Write a bunch of code to pick the right phrase(s).

Comment: What? I don't honestly see a relation of your answer with my question o.O