# Does "Inheritance" Make Sense with This Requirement?

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-12c, subtypes

I'm using Oracle 12c. Given an existing table (we call it `TBL_M`), and based on the criteria below, I was wondering if using inheritance makes sense to lay out the entities:

Information for one group of data (we call it *Group One*):

```
RATE
AMOUNT
FREQUENCY
```

And information for another group of data (we call it *Group Two*):

```
RATE
AMOUNT
FREQUENCY
DEPTH
```

So the columns needed for this become:

**TBL_P**

```
TBL_P_ID
RATE
AMOUNT
FREQUENCY
TBL_M_ID (fk)
```

**TBL_C**

```
TBL_C_ID
DEPTH
TBL_P_ID (fk)
```

For *Group Two*, every time we want to make an entry, we populate both tables (`TBL_P` and `TBL_C`). However, when the information is for *Group One*, `TBL_P.TBL_M_ID` is going to be set to `NULL` redundantly.

Would it be more efficient to split this into two separate tables, one for *Group One*, and the other for *Group Two*? e.g.

**TBL_ONE**

```
TBL_ONE_ID
RATE
AMOUNT
FREQUENCY
TBL_M_ID (fk)
```

**TBL_TWO**

```
TBL_TWO_ID
RATE
AMOUNT
FREQUENCY
DEPTH
TBL_M_ID (fk)
```

Comment: You might find of help [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149951/63644).

Comment: Thank you. That post was very well thought out. I ended up using a single table with all the shared and unshared data as I found it redundant to create that `TBL_C` for a single column. 70% of times, that column (`DEPTH`) is going to be populated, and only in 30% of cases would be `NULL`. The table only gets inserted with 3 rows every day, and roughly ~300+ a year. Number of daily reads would be around 1000/day.