# How to design a database with product-dependent columns?

Tags: database-design

I am very new to database design. I have a task to create an inventory program with  asp.net core and entity framework core.

The inventory program will be used to manage various kind of products. Products have some common fields (aka columns) such as:

- `ProductId`
- `Contidion` (new, 2nd hand)
- `Price`
- etc

But each product also has some specific fields. For example, a mother board has

- `MemorySlots` (either 2, 4, etc)
- `MemoryType` (DDR2, DDR3, etc)
- `CpuType` (Amd, Intel)
- etc

Another product, for example, is a book. It has:

- `ISBN`
- `Authors`
- `Title`
- etc

## Question

How can I manage the product-specific fields in a database?

Comment: You might find of help [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149951/63644).

Comment: @all: thank you for the given useful links. Please don't remove them. :-)